# Can a Polyhedron have infinite vertex or edge set ? - and what is the exact definition of a solid.

Tags: geometry

I've been reading about Polyhedrons through the following article.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron

My question is:

Can a Polyhedron have infinite vertex or edge set ? If not, what does imply that this isn't possible ?

Also, what is the exact definition of a solid ?

Comment: This might be of interest: http://www.superliminal.com/geometry/infinite/infinite.htm